# Ajax call being skipped

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, requirejs, kendo-mobile

I'm having an issue with the javascript below in which the `$.ajax` call is not being called.  The `alert('foo')` does happen, but then the data call is completely skipped and the callback is never reached (never get `alert('success!')`.  I don't completely understand callbacks, but this seems like it should be working.

**Edit**

Edited the script to where I currently stand, as I've read this way is better practice.  Still, I can step in to `authenticate()`, it breaks on `url:[...]`, but then never actually makes the ajax call.  I've tried removing the return just to see if that's the problem, but it's producing the same result.

```
define(["jQuery", "kendo", "modernizr", "app/environment"], function ($, kendo, modernizr, environment) {
    var authenticate = function (username, password) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: environment.apiConnection + '/canlogin?userid=' + username + '&password=' + password,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
    }

    var canLogin = function(data) {
        alert('good');
    }

    return {
        viewModel: kendo.observable({
            username: null,
            password: null,
            authenticate: function () {
                var username = this.get('username'),
                    password = this.get('password');

                authenticate(username, password).done(canLogin);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: jsonp request cannot be sync

Comment: I see, thanks.  Does anyone have the proper way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Do you get a script error on the ajax line? Or something funny with `environment.apiConnection`?

Comment: Negative, I even just tried hardcoding it and got the same result.  One change I just tried, changing canlogin to not take a callback and  `return $.ajax[...]`.  Then I called it like this `canLogin(username, password).done(authenticate)` where authenticate just looks like `alert('foo')`... Anyways, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a mixture of `e.preventDefault()` and using a callback in the ajax call.  Just using the callback didn't resolve the issue, but adding `preventDefault` to the `authenticate` function and fixing the callback issue did.

The final, working version, now looks something like this:

```
define(["jQuery", "kendo", "modernizr", "app/environment"], function ($, kendo, modernizr, environment) {
    function authenticate(username, password, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: environment.apiConnection + '/canlogin?userid=' + username + '&password=' + password,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: callback,
            error: function (x,t,r) {
                console.log('error')
            }
        });
    }

    function login(canLogin, username, password) {
        if (canLogin == false) {
            alert('Incorrect username or password');
            return;
        }

        alert('good');
    }

    return {
        viewModel: kendo.observable({
            username: null,
            password: null,
            authenticate: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var username = this.get('username'),
                    password = this.get('password');

                authenticate(username, password, function (canLogin) {
                    login(canLogin, username, password);
                });
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback instead.

```
var canLogin = function (username, password, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: config.apiConnection + '/canlogin?userid=' + username + '&password=' + password,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        error: function (x, t, r) {
            alert('Error');
        },
        success: callback
    });

}

// use
canLogin("user","passwd",function( data ){
    alert("Im called on authentication success!");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but it still didn't work.  I noticed that the API call isn't happening either (unless I break on $.ajax, and step over it, then it works)